# Trying Cybersource with Hybris 6.1

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Hi i am new to hybris & i have hybris 6.1, Now i want to use Cybersource integration with my hybris. But it needs b2ccheckout addon which is not included in hybris package. I have commented the " -->" in cybersourceaddon/extensioninfo.xml.\,but while ant clean all it gives the error import de.hybris.platform.acceleratorfacades.order.impl.DefaultAcceleratorCheckoutFacade;
   [yjavac]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   [yjavac] The import de.hybris.platform.acceleratorfacades.order.impl cannot be resolved

Answer (score 1):

*Cybersource* extension is not part of the SAP Hybris commerce distribution anymore. Where did you find this extension ?

Deleting dependencies is not how you are going to fix this.

Have a look at the [documentation](https://help.hybris.com/6.1.0/hcd/8ad0893686691014bd38f4e952a38e29.html).

Comment: Yeah, agree with that, you should now be using the payment extension

Answer (score 0):

For integrating cybersource with Hybris, first you need to install the addon using the below command:

```
ant addoninstall -Daddonnames="**CyberSourceAddonName**" -DaddonStorefront.yacceleratorstorefront="**YourStoreFrontName**"
```

**CyberSourceAddonName** could be cybersourcepaymentaddon,cybersourceb2bpaymentaddon

Also add the extensions to localextensions.xml file:

```
<extension name='cybersourcepayment' />
<extension name='cybersourcepaymentaddon' />
<extension name='cybersourceb2bpaymentaddon' />
<extension name='cybersourcefulfilmentprocess' />
```

These should resolve your issues.